# The menu on my site goes down when the browser size is reduced and at a resolution of less than 1024x768

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The menu on my site goes down when the browser size is reduced and at a resolution of less than 1024x768, the site is here: shororus.ru. Site is on WordPress.

Comment: In order for questions to be useful even after the problem is fixed, we ask for a demonstration of the problem in your question itself. Would you edit your question to provide that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @NooBCodeR! It seems to be your first question, so I recommend you to read the page [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you provide more details and snippets of your code where you think it is the error, it will be easier for the community to help you. The first task before to ask is always research in Internet about your problem, even in Stack Overflow, because it is possible that someone has asked something similar or someone have received an answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at getting a mobile menu plugin such as WP Mobile Menu (https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-menu/) so that you can set at what pixels the mobile menu should display. By customising the amount of pixels in the required plugin, as you shrink it down it should just convert to a mobile menu and not force the menu off of the header.

Hope this helps.